# A Multistep Reaction Provided with IR Spectra (Guessing Started with Esterification)

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, ir-spectroscopy

[image: Reaction Scheme]

Below, IR spectra for this sequence are provided:

[image: IR Spectra]

For compound **E**, I suggest the formation of a conjugated ester with the elimination of $\ce{-OH}$ group. The IR peak at $\pu{1732 cm-1}$ is a reasonable value for $\ce{C=O}$ stretch of ester.

Subsequently for **F**, I suggest the presence of a hydroxyl group due to the strong peak at $\pu{3400 cm-1}$. The reformation of hydroxyl group from $\ce{C=C}$ is unlikely due to the conjugated system. Plus, hydrolysis of ester will give broad $\ce{-OH}$ peak which is unlikely from the spectrum. Hence, I am inclined to suggest  vinylogue Michael addition of compound **D** to yield compound **F**. However, I am hesitant because of the possibility of dehydration.

For compound **G**, I would like to suggest the presence of alkyne yet the peak is strong. Possibly, would it be $\ce{CO2}$? If decarboxylation occurs, compound **F** must be β-keto-acid which is generated after hydrolysis of ester. The nucleophilic attack from compound **D** would also attack the carbonyl group instead of the $\ce{C=C}$ bond of compound **E**.

| Compound | Suggestion |
| --- | --- |
| **E** | [image: Text] |
| **F** | [image: Text] |
| **F'** | [image: Text] |
| **F''** | [image: Text] |

Possibly, my reasoning is wrong at the first place. I am confused currently. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

After reading the suggestion, I consider the potential of O-nucleophile. Reversible acidic hydrolysis of ester, **E** can form acrylic acid. Then, it will  form acrylic anhydride. The conjugated system might lower the C=O stretch to lower frequency. Is this plausible? Is the condition suitable for the formation of acid anhydride without phosphorous pentoxide? However, I am still clueless for compound **G**.

Comment: consider the possibility of lactone formation

Comment: The suggest of the metharcylate **E** makes sense given the reaction conditions and comparison of the IR spectrum given to you with an experimental spectrum by AIST/SDBS (entry [SDBS 1220](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/landingpage?sdbsno=1220)).  Does the original question really truncate provision of the conditions/reagents for $\ce{E -> F -> G}$?  Or, does it state that $\ce{D -> G}$ proceeds by telescoping/a one-pot procedure?

Comment: @Buttonwood The original question only states that this is a multistep reaction sequence. I am unsure about the possibility of one-pot procedure. However, only conditions/reagents are shown for the first step. I believe the subsequent steps will follow the similar conditions.

Comment: @Waylander Except for cropping the header, replacing English `transmittance` and `wavenumber` by Chinese, this is copying the work by AIST/SDBS (entry 1220 mentioned earlier) without proper credit where (to whom) is credit is due.